# Dynamic variable names (at runtime) in Python

Tags: python

I predefine some variables and want call them in a *for* loop:

```
a1 = 10
a2 = 20 
for i in range(1, 3):
  value=("a%s" %i)
  print(value)
```

And I get a1,a2, but I want to have 10,20. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You should not do that. If you want multiple "related" variables, use a structure such as a `list` or a `tuple` and iterate over it.

Comment: The string must be evaluated, otherwise it’s just that, a string.  Additionally, this is asking for trouble later on.  I’d recommend not doing this at all.

Comment: `a = [10, 20] for i in range(1,3): value = a[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Accessing `globals()` should do the trick, but there are better ways to do this (see comments on your original post)

```py
a1=10
a2=20 
for i in range(1,3):
  value=("a%s" %i)
  print(globals()[value])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to loop through `a1` and `a2`, you want to put them in a collection and loop through that:

```
a1=10
a2=20
combined = a1, a2
for i in combined:
  print(i)
```

Output

```
10
20
```